# JSON.parse JSON string in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to get a variable ($total_news_array, which contains an array of different news items by title, time posted, etc) from a PHP file into a JS one. I have the following code in my JS file:

```
$(function() {
    function reqListener() {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }

    var tweet_object = new Object();

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
    oReq.onload = function() {
        //alert(this.responseText);
        var json_tweet_data = this.responseText;
        alert(json_tweet_data);
        tweet_object = JSON.parse(json_tweet_data);
        //alert(tweet_object);
    };
    oReq.open("get", "variables_for_js.php", true);
    oReq.send();
```

When I use `alert(this.responseText)` or `alert(json_tweet_data)`, which contains `this.response` text, I am getting the object alerted to my screen like this:

[image]

However, when I `alert(tweet_object)`, which should be the JSON-parsed form of that object displayed to my screen, I'm getting the following:
`[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

[image]

From what I've seen in other threads, my JSON-parse command should be working, and converting that JSON string into object tweet_object. I apologize in advance if I'm missing something simple - thanks to anyone who can tell me why this isn't working.

Comment: This is exactly why you shouldn't use `alert()` to debug, it coerces all types to a string. Your code is working fine. You just need to use `console.log` to see the output correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON.parse` call is working perfectly fine. However, once parsed, the `tweet_object` variable is an array of JS objects. If you try to convert an object to a string, the result is `[object Object]`. Try this in your console: `({} + ' ')` (an object literal, concatenated with a space).

An array, on the other hand *extends* the base `Object` prototype (`Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([]))` -> get the prototype, of the prototype of an array. The result is `Object {}`). When an array is coerced to a string, it has the same effect as `[].join(',')`. Joining with a comma as delimiter.
This is what happens here. your `alert` is converting the array to a string, concatenating its values using comma's for delimiters. Because each value is an object, the only possible result is a string like the one you're getting: `[object Object],[object, Object],...`.

To get at a specific value in this array of objects, do as you normally would in JS:

```
for (var i=0;i<tweet_object.length;++i) {
    console.log(tweet_object[i].id);//or alert
}
```

### TL;TR

What is happening:

1. `alert(tweet_object)` is passing an array to `alert`. Alert coerces the argument to a string
2. Arrays are coerced to a string by concatenating all the values, using a comma as a delimiter
3. Each value is an object literal, which yields `[object Object]` when coerced to a string. They are being coerced to strings because the containing array is being coerced to a string (`alert`).

These three points explain the output:

```
[object Object], [object Object],...
     /\       /\       /\
   object  delimiter  object
```

#### So what now?

There was a point in time where people used to litter their code with `alert`'s and custom functions to traverse objects and output them in a meaningful way. Thankfully, those days are long gone, and we now just dump variables, regardless of their value to the console (`console.log`). The console can handle any JS type: strings, objects, functions, ... doesn't matter. If you want to know what an object looks like, just `console.log` it.
When debugging code, use the tools that give you the most information about the thing you want to inspect. String representations of values almost always fall short...

Answer (score 4):

I believe everything actually works fine, just the `alert()` function can not present the json data correctly, try to use the `console.log(json_tweet_data)` instead.

When you call the `alert(this.responseText)` you are actually looking on the json string, not on the parsed JSON. Once you parse it the `alert` just can't display it any more.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably working just fine. The `alert` is trying to turn an array of objects into a string, and when a regular object is turned into a string you get `[object Object]`. Try `console.log` and look at your dev console instead.